# How complex one line of code can be to be also easy readable?

Tags: python

I have one line of code that is returning certain price from Amazon website. I'm wondering if my code is readable.

This is my line of code:

```
price = float(amazon_soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "a-offscreen"}).getText().split("$")[1])
```

Or maybe it is readable because it returns only price, just like name of the variable says?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is opinion based, and my opinion is it is clearly not readable. Given that you ask the question, you also have doubts

Comment: Note that the moment you add some proper error handling, etc. it will no longer be a one-liner anyway

Comment: Thank You. Yes, I have doubts, but I wonder how to separate it. Maybe make variable named 'span_object = amazon_soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "a-offscreen"}).getText()' and then make variable called 'price = float(span_object.split("$")[1]'
This would be better?

Comment: As I said, this is opinion-based, thus off-topic here. Your question may be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The readability of code is actually subjective. Readability of a code itself is the ability to make the code easily understood by other programmers. For some it is not readable, for others it is.

As a programmer who will read this code, what I can say is, shorter lines doesn't always mean the code is more readable compared to multiple lines. Considering breaking down the code to multiple lines so your code will explain the whole step by step process of getting the price (as the variables says) can improve the readability (as I said, it is subjective but breaking it down into pieces can make it more easy to digest).

```
price_span = amazon_soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "a-offscreen"})
      
# Extract the text content from the span element
price_text = price_span.getText()
         
# Split the text to get the price value after the "$" symbol
price = float(price_text.split("$")[1])
```

Adding comments makes it more readable as it describes the purpose of the code.

**Optional**: You can put the whole logic inside a function so it is reusable and it can be called in one line.

```
def get_price:
   price_span = amazon_soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "a-offscreen"})
          
   # Extract the text content from the span element
   price_text = price_span.getText()
             
   # Split the text to get the price value after the "$" symbol
   price = float(price_text.split("$")[1])
```

So when you call it somewhere in your code:

```
get_price()
```

If you want to apply best practices to improve readability, you might want to check the [PEP guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) of python for this.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a solo project, you do you

However, it's true that it's a bit long for a single line,
you can always just add spaces or variables to make it a bit more readable
or add comments

```
query = amazon_soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "a-offscreen"})
# Extract the price from the text found
price = float(query.getText().split("$")[1])
```

or

```
price = float(
  amazon_soup.find(
    "span",
    attrs={"class": "a-offscreen"}
  ).getText().split("$")[1]
)
```

But again, your code, your choice